# Visibility toggling

Tags: c#, wpf

In my XAML, there's one button and one label. At launch, the button is visible and the label is not. When clicking the `install_btn`, the label should becomes visible instead of the button.
Here's a part of the code:

```
private void install_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    inst_label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    progress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    install_btn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

And then there's some code like `webClient.DownloadFile()`. But the visibility toggles only after processing the webClient. How can I perform toggling before downloading files (or something else)?

Comment: You'll have to show us some more code. What is this webclient.DownloadFile part of the code that is missing?

Comment: Don't download on UI thread, your application will look hung. Move downloading into a separate thread (preferably using tasks, because the code will be simplest).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should allow the application to update it's UI:

```
private void install_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    inst_label.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    progress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    install_btn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
    webClient.DownloadFile();
}
```

Comment: You should instead have the file download be done asynchronously. Use `webClient.DownloadFileAsync` instead. Using a dispatcher to update the UI is a horrible idea.